# Why is my filter not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, filtering

I have got a set of **Gym Classes** which gets pulled from the database, this is the log of that:

[image]

When it gets pulled they get put into two different arrays:

```
gymClasses: [],
filteredClasses: [],
```

Then when a user clicks one of the dropdowns it gets the value of the selected dropdown with the `this.filterClasses(event.target.value);`

Then the function to that runs this:

```
filterClasses(value) {
  const newFilteredClasses = this.state.gymClasses.filter( (value) => {
    return this.state.gymClasses.type === value;
  });

  this.setState({filterClasses: newFilteredClasses});
  console.log('values ', this.state.filteredClasses);
}
```

When I open the last console.log which is supposed to show me the `filteredClasses` it shows me the same classes like the ones which did not get filtered.

This is the result of the last

`console.log('values ', this.state.filteredClasses);`

[image]

Any advice of help would be appreciated!

Comment: One thing to notice, [state updates may be async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so console logging after it does not imply that you'll get the state you want. For this you can use a callback function in `setState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the filter callback, you are checking type of

```
this.state.gymClasses.type === value
```

Ideally you should use callback `param` instead of `this.state.gymClasses.type`

try this

```
filterClasses(selectedValue) {
  const newFilteredClasses = this.state.gymClasses.filter( (value) => {
    return value.type === selectedValue;
  });

  this.setState({filterClasses: newFilteredClasses});
}
```

Comment: The `gymClasses.type` `type` means the type of class not the `typeof`.

Comment: what I get from `filterClasses` method is, you want the filtered array from `gymClasses` depending selected value, correct?

Comment: Correct, I've got two arrays, one called `gymClasses` which stays untouched and the `filterClasses ` which obviously gets filtered and we want to display the filtered classes, but even after changing it, I still get the 3 classes after filtering.

Comment: you can't console immediately after `setState`. try to console `newFilteredClasses`

Comment: Good point, I shouldn't be console.logging after setState, If I log that I get an empty array. @Harish

Comment: console the new array where you are using `filterClasses` or in `render`

Comment: It's not empty anymore, I found that the form was storing it differently, with no spaces, fixed it and now it's returning one class only as it should be! So well done thats right. @Harish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183634/discussion-between-andrew-and-harish).